# Are there any resources for numerical methods in extracting coefficients from generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, generating-functions

Oftentimes in combinatorics, one can derive a closed form for a generating function, say $F(z)$, describing some scenario. From this function, we can extract the coefficient of $z^k$ to arrive at an answer for our counting problem. When $k$ is especially large however, the real problem sometimes lies in finding this coefficient. While there are times in which we can expand $F(z)$ in terms of geometric series and find the coefficients analytically, I believe that this isn't always true, thus I'm looking for some numerical methods to extract these coefficients.

The only real method I've seem to come up with (as opposed to taking many derivatives, which also does not seem to be very numerically stable) is one involving Fourier analysis methods and the orthogonality of exponential functions. In other words, if
$$F(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n z^n,$$
then
$$[z^k]F(z) = a_k = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_0^{2 \pi} F(e^{it}) \> e^{-ikt} \, dt.$$
In the case that $F(z)$ is not defined for $|z| = 1$, we can pick some constant $C \in (0, 1)$ and see similarly that
$$a_k = \frac{C^{-k}}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} F(Ce^{it}) \> e^{-ikt} \, dt.$$
However, in my experience, these are pretty finicky to use and not very numerically stable. For large values of $k$, they certainly aren't easy to work with. Thus my questions is: are there any common or general numerical methods for extracting coefficients of (large) powers in generating functions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If $F(z)$ can be represented as a Taylor-Maclaurin series, the $a_n$ are accessible via the $n$-th derivative, because $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}F^{(n)}(z)|_0$. Often, the $a_n$ can be represented in closed form via exponential Bell polynomials for many not too complicated functions.

Comment: If you have some values of your series, you can use the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS) to get more insight.

Comment: @IV_ That is absolutely horrible answer as numerical differentiation is well-known to be ill-conditioned.

Comment: I'm not sure what algorithm you are calculating the integral with, but if $k$ isn't too large some form of FFT/iFFT version could be used that should be reasonably stable (assuming you can calculate $F$ to reasonable accuracy).  Of course, if $k$ is really large this might not be feasible or you reach accuracy you could compute the variation of $F(Ce^{2\pi ij/n})$ between adjacent points $j$ then the information is already lost.

Comment: @user10354138 It's not numerical differentiation, it's automatic differentiation. And calculating Bell polynomials (integer partitions) is easily feasible.